# Are WorkManager workers meant to run when the application is killed / not running?

Tags: android, android-workmanager

I wrote a periodic worker that runs just fine when the app is at the front or in the background (recents) but when I clean it from the recents it does not run anymore.

I have heard people saying requests should run even when the app is killed, but I've also seen cases where developers of famous applications had to write a Service instead just because of similar complaints from users.

My WorkManager library version is `androidx.work:work-runtime:2.4.0`.

I tested on both a physical `Android 10` Xiaomi device and a `Android 10` Nexus 5X API 29 (x86_64) device.

I know that Xiaomi's MIUI has battery optimizations that might interfere and I even tried with the `Autostart` setting set for the app to no avail, but why would it happen on a fresh AVD image then ?

Answer (score 0):

"WorkManager is intended for work that is deferrable—that is, not required to run immediately—and required to run reliably even if the app exits or the device restarts."

That being said the Android system can instruct your app to stop the WorkRequest for a number of different reasons. Ex. A WorkRequest will be stopped if it exceeds the execution deadline by 10 minutes.